# Setting variable to be undetermined in a ternary operator

Tags: ternary-operator

How do I make a variable to stay undefined in a ternary operator?
For example
    (var == 2)? var = 3 : (var stays undetermined);

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: If I try to leave it empty like this:  var == 2? var = 3 : ;  then the compiler says that it expected primary-expression before ';' token

Comment: What language are we even talking about?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as **unclear what you're asking**, seeing how OP didn't even manage to specify the language after several month.